# Update DOM angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a controller that fetches images using service and builds up DOM as following,

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="image in images">
            <img parentimageclick="{{ image.standard_resolution.url }}" ng-src={{image.thumbnail.url}} />
        </li>
</ul>
```

Now using directive I'm calling a service via same controller

```
    Products.directive("parentimageclick",function(){
        var parentimageclick = function(scope,element,attrs) {
              element.bind('click',function(){
                 scope.callChild(attrs.src);
              });
        };
        return parentimageclick;
    });
```

As you see callChild for controller is called which calls service

```
$scope.callChild = function(data) {
    packImage.prepareSend(data);
}
```

Service code is,

```
    Products.factory('packImage',function($rootScope){

     var packImage = {};
     packImage.img = "";

      packImage.prepareSend = function(img) {
          this.img = img;
          this.Send();
      }

     packImage.Send = function(){
          $rootScope.$broadcast('takeimage');
     }

     return packImage;
    });
```

So basically i use this service to access the clicked image in another controller as follows,

```
    Products.controller('PackCtrl',function($scope,packImage){

         var images = [];

         $scope.$on('takeimage', function() {
                       //console.log(packImage.img);
                       var data = {
                       url: packImage.img,
                       };

             images.push(data);
             $scope.images = images;
             $scope.$apply();
            });

   });
```

Now problem with the above code is it does populate the dom as model updates but what I'm really trying to achieve is different. cuz my DOM remain same.

For eg, i have a hardcode list in my dom as follows,

```
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>

    //Ten of them
  </ul>
```

So i couldn't change the above structure and i need some functionality where if the image is fetched in the controller it needs to find the empty list item and append it there. This has to be done until list is finished.

Update:

This http://jsfiddle.net/CQzu5/ should be about rough demo of what i want to do? hope there is an angular way to do same.

Comment: @charlietfl i have a list already i.e. 10 elements now every time i get a new image from other controller i need to find the empty list item and put the image inside it.

Comment: don't understand why you can't use ng-repeat on the other list also. Issue is not clear at all. WHat does `DOM remain same` mean?

Comment: A demo of your situation in plunker or jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: If all your directive `parentimageclick` does is register a click handler, just use `ng-click=callChild(image.thumbnail.url)` in your `img` element.

Comment: @charlietfl does this help? http://i.imgur.com/eHl2kSQ.png you can see the above empty boxes are where images go one by one every time we click

Comment: @jelinson yes i can do that but I'm creating a json out of different attributes so by on click it will be sort of redundancy to pass as parameter.

Comment: no, image doesn't help...create a demo. How can anyone help you with code based on an image.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry about late reply, yes http://jsfiddle.net/CQzu5/ this should help. Its a pseudo version of what i want to do. So text will be replaced by actual images. You need to click on the text to know. Is there an angular way to do this?

Comment: push images into array and use ng-repeat, or ng-show not jQuery. Still not clear from demo the exact behavior you want

Comment: @charlietfl yes that works fine. But ng-repeat works only when images are selected but i need to have some generic list that is empty on page load and as on images are selected it find first empty list element and clones it there.

Comment: @charlietfl am i making much sense here? Just a generic empty list that has borders and when images are clicked images is cloned inside that empty border

Comment: I don't think you understand how angular works. Can use `ng-src` for one image, or have all images in container and use `ng-show`. I'm not 100% clear exactly how you wnt this,  but if you understand angular at all it's not very complicated. If you don't understand angular...don't use it

Comment: @charlietfl l0l yeah I'm kinda trying to pick it up but thats cool thanks for your reply.

Comment: if you would simply outline exact behavior wanted, and provide some sample data in demo I could help more. Can use flicker pics or something similar